# Renaming all columns in a batch - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I want to replace all column names in the old dataset "olddata" with new names saved in a data frame "newnames"

In basic R it's simple and works

```
colnames(olddata) <- t(as.vector(newnames))
```

However an attempt with dplyr:

```
olddata <- olddata %>% rename(vars(everything()), ~t(newnames))
```

Returns an error:

```
Error: Must rename columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `quosures`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.
```

**What might be wrong here?** Thank you!

Comment: That seems overly complicated. To rename all columns you can use `rename_with()` like that: `mtcars %>% rename_with(~newnames)`. `newnames` being a vector.

Comment: How does the data frame `"newnames"` looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `newnames` is a one column `data.frame`, you can convert it to vector using:

```
newnames %>% pull(1)
```

then you can rename your `olddata` with:

```
olddata <- olddata %>% rename_with(~ newnames %>% pull(1))
```

Here is some testing with some hypothetical data:

```
newnames <- data.frame(letters[1:3])

# letters.1.3.
# 1            a
# 2            b
# 3            c

olddata <- data.frame(col_1 = 1, col_2 = 2, col_3 = 3)

# col_1 col_2 col_3
# 1     1     2     3

olddata <- olddata %>% rename_with(~ newnames %>% pull(1))

# a b c
# 1 1 2 3
```